# Mac .bash_profile double quotes (straight and curly)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

[image]

While running alias **bb** I was getting error.

```
. .bash_profile 
-bash: alias: off: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: “open: not found
-bash: alias: -e: not found
-bash: alias: .bash_profile”: not found
```

Upon further investing I found its due to the way double quotes are automatically changed from **straight-quotes** to **curly-quotes** in mac. 
So I changed keyboard preferences of Mac to **straight-quotes** and now alias **bp** works fine.

I wonder why the **curly-quotes** didn't work in bash, took me a while to figure out the issue.

Comment: You might as well ask why you can't quote a string with a pair of `%`; straight quotes are what `bash` expects.

Comment: @Andrew Medico and others, This question was closed saying "its a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" Really, first of all this problem can be reproduced, even though its a typographical errors, its not a "simple" one to figure. I along with my colleague spent almost an hour to figure whats going on and we are not newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bash supports several types of quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to delimit strings, but *not* typographic ones. They will be considered as just another character.